# ErrorCode:AccessDenied, Message:AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ios7

my app is working fine in ios 6.. it uploading and downloading the data from amazon web server s3..but when i upgrade my ios 6 to ios 7...i got alert message " cannot connect to server" this error in log window

"Exception = AmazonServiceException { RequestId:5DC8AEF01DD9FB91, ErrorCode:AccessDenied, Message:AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header} ".

to solve this problem i upgrade my aws ios sdk 1.0.0 to aws ios sdk 1.6.1.and try to run my app it freezes for 10-12 second then app running.

so please can anyone tell me the solution how i remove " x-amz-date header" problem in aws ios sdk 1.0.0 and its alternate freeze problem in aws ios sdk 1.6.1..

Comment: I have the same problem with aws ios sdk 1.4

Comment: I have the same problem; looking at the data that is being sent to Amazon I noticed that the format of the Date header differs slightly between iOS6 and iOS7, and most likely this is what throws the date parser on Amazon's end off.

iOS6: Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 07:58:18 GMT+10:00
iOS7: Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2013 07:58:18 GMT+10

So the hour part of the TZ offset seems missing in iOS7.

Comment: so How you solve that?,IS any method to solve this hour part in ios7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have submitted a bug report to Apple (to find out if this a bug or not).

In the meantime I created an awful hack that solves the issue in S3Request.m in 
the method configureURLRequest:

```
NSString *checkFormat =[self.date requestFormat];
if(![checkFormat hasSuffix:@":00"])
    checkFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:00",checkFormat];
[self.urlRequest setValue:checkFormat forHTTPHeaderField:kHttpHdrDate];
```

This may not be the same in your version of the AWS SDK.

I would not use this fix in the long term - I will post any response from the Apple bug report team here once they come back with a recommended solution

I also posted a question here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=135829#

EDIT: in the latest version of the toolkit the hack is:

```
NSString *checkFormat =[self.date stringWithRFC822Format];
if(![checkFormat hasSuffix:@":00"])
    checkFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:00",checkFormat];
[self.urlRequest setValue:checkFormat forHTTPHeaderField:kHttpHdrDate];
```

Answer (score 3):

In `AmazonSDKUtil.m`, we have the following methods:

```
+(NSDate *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *)string usingFormat:(NSString *)dateFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[AmazonSDKUtil timestampLocale]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

    NSDate *parsed = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];

    NSDate *localDate = [parsed dateByAddingTimeInterval:_clockskew];

    [dateFormatter release];

    return localDate;
}

+(NSString *)convertDateToString:(NSDate *)date usingFormat:(NSString *)dateFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[AmazonSDKUtil timestampLocale]];

    NSDate *realDate =  [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1*_clockskew];

    NSString *formatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:realDate];

    [dateFormatter release];

    return formatted;
}
```

In older versions of the SDK, the locale and timezone weren't properly set to `en_US` and `GMT`. This may cause issues depending on your device locale and timezone settings. The latest version of the SDK fixes the issue. If, for some reason, you cannot update the SDK, you can modify `AmazonSDKUtil.m` and explicitly set locale and timezone values.

**EDIT:**

If you run the following code snippet on iOS 6 and iOS 7, you can see how locale setting affects date format.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PDT"];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];

NSString *dateWithoutTimezoneAndLocale = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Date 1: %@", dateWithoutTimezoneAndLocale);

dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

NSString *dateWithTimezoneAndLocale = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Date 2: %@", dateWithTimezoneAndLocale);
```

**On iOS 6**

```
Date 1: Wed, 25 Sep 2013 16:25:29 PDT
Date 2: Wed, 25 Sep 2013 23:25:29 GMT
```

**On iOS 7**

```
Date 1: Wed, 25 Sep 2013 16:24:11 GMT-7
Date 2: Wed, 25 Sep 2013 23:24:11 GMT
```

As you stated before, the behavior of `NSDateFormatter` changed in iOS 7; however, the root cause of this issue is that you are not explicitly setting the locale to `en_US`. When the locale is set to something other than `en_US`, it may cause an issue. This is why we explicitly set the locale in the latest version of our SDK so that it runs on devices with any locale settings.

Hope this makes sense,

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a solution - I tried it two projects and both failed with this new code.  I still agree with @patschiboy that the errors lies with the format of the date as supplied by ios7

Comment: Properly setting the locale and timezone should solve the date/time formatting issue as indicated in my edited answer. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail - I will try and report back if any issues but this makes sense

Comment: Yosuke - as further information Apple came back to me and stated regarding ios7:    There is support for two lengths of localized GMT format per locale, long (e.g. "GMT-08:00") and short (e.g. "GMT-8"). And 'z' is now explicitly specified to fallback to the short localized GMT format. Still, there can be variation among locales in exactly what that looks like.

If you want to have an invariant form, then you should use one of the ISO 8601 styles, with pattern characters using X or x; see the zone section of
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

Comment: Finally got round to properly testing this out and your method of GMT and en_US (as shown in Date 2 example) looks good - thanks Yosuke!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Got the Solution and This works for me,i used awsios sdk 1.3.1 instead of    awsios sdk 1.6.1. and make some changes in S3Request.m in the method

```
-(AmazonURLRequest *)configureURLRequest{
   ....
     ....

   NSString *checkFormat =[self.date stringWithRFC822Format];
   if(![checkFormat hasSuffix:@":00"])
    checkFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@+00:00",checkFormat];
   [self.urlRequest setValue:checkFormat forHTTPHeaderField:kHttpHdrDate];
   ...
     ...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was had the same problem and after updating to version 1.6 of AWS SDK the problem has gone.