# amazon s3client , awsios sdk framework , giving exception in iOS 7

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWSiOS sdk framework, when i create bucket, it throws an exception, 
    `AmazonServiceException { RequestId:94225DB70E9F667E, ErrorCode:AccessDenied, Message:AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header` in iOS 7 but same is running fine in iOS 6. Has anyone done that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a locale issue. Setting `en_US` as its locale to `NSDateFormatter` will solve the issue. Please refer to my answer on this forum for more details:
[ErrorCode:AccessDenied, Message:AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933208/errorcodeaccessdenied-messageaws-authentication-requires-a-valid-date-or-x-am/18990717#18990717)

Comment: i have set my locale to en_US , but didnt work , same results

Comment: Have you run the code snippet I posted on the other post? You should run it and see if you can recreate the same result.